# Model looks strange when zoomed out

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, camera, sculpting

The head of my character looked completely fine as I sculpted it in perspective view. Obviously, adding the body required me to zoom out to view the entire model. By doing this, however, the head that I sculpted earlier looked completely different. It turns out that the head becomes more "orthographic" the more I zoom out. Is there any way I can view the entire body while keeping the head in its "perspective" form?

[image]

PROBLEM: The left image shows what the head looks like when viewing the entire body. Zooming out causes the facial features to be "scrunched", and the face looks flattened. Although the camera is pointed directly at the character, the entire head appears to be tilted upwards a bit. The eyes also seem crossed.

DESIRED: The right image shows what the head looks like when the camera is zoomed in, exactly how it looked while I was sculpting it.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the **"camera size"** in properties object camera to enlarge your image while keep all light angle stay in place:

[image]
[image]
This is the thing that every photographer in real world want to increase, you can do it in Blender for free. *Thank you, Blender.*

Comment: Adjusting the camera settings such as the camera size may fix the head but it stretches out the body in extreme proportions. I eventually discovered that the problem is a result of 2.79's incorrect default viewport lens angle of 35, whereas most viewports are above 50. This has been corrected in 2.8, which I don't have. This means that the only way to fix the model is to either adjust or remake the model with the correct viewport lens angle -- not by adjusting the camera settings.

Comment: @MooKorea Another way is to use post-editing to remove that distortion (lens distortion) in render image. Maybe in Photoshop or GIMP, they should give you a good control without much effort then remodeling your character

Answer (score 0):

## Please consider the possibility there is no problem here at all

There is no incorrect value for focal length. The term does not apply. Various focal lengths are common through the history of lenses. Our eyes have no such parameter, because of the way they work but are considered to be close to 43-45mm on 35mm sensor by many, but most natural perspective is debatable and you can find people considering anything from around 25 to 70 to be natural. It depends on the subject observed as well.

People are used to various focal lengths in pictures. This will not be considered a problem by vast majority of your artwork observers and does not contribute much to the visual communication in this particular case. It is very common to see people this way for everyone, because this is the only way we do see other people - once we get further away perspective of the face changes in exactly the same way. Your worries here have no logic.

In fact in portrait photography 'less perspective' is often considered to be desirable. It is common to use 50-85 mm lenses to make faces look more like the image you marked as a problem.

I suspect you are overthinking this and wasting your resources(time) trying to solve this 'problem'. I would suggest looking at your model from various perspectives while modelling/sculpting and adjust it as needed the way you like it if you must, but accepting that it's going to look a bit differently from different distances because of how physics work.